# how to hide button in reactjs . click the button to hide

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSDon.png)

please help click the button complete hide using reactJs in class component

please check the image and please give corrected code

```js
import React,{Component} from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default class ButtonDemo extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        isDisabled: false 
      }
  }
  handSubmit(){
    this.setState({
      isDisabled: true
  })
  }
      render() {
        return (
    <div>
      <input></input>
      <button disabled={this.state.isDisabled} onClick={() => this.handSubmit()}>submit</button>
    </div>
  );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'd like to remind to approve the answer which helped you out.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default class ButtonDemo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isDisabled: false,
    };
  }
  handSubmit() {
    this.setState({
      isDisabled: true,
    });
  }
  render() {
    const buttonStyling = this.state.isDisabled ? {display: "none;"} : {};

    return (
      <div>
        <input></input>
        <button style={buttonStyling} disabled={this.state.isDisabled} onClick={() => this.handSubmit()}>
          submit
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Another possible solution would be to implement **conditional rendering** for the button:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default class ButtonDemo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isDisabled: false,
    };
  }
  handSubmit() {
    this.setState({
      isDisabled: true,
    });
  }
  render() {
   

    return (
      <div>
        <input></input>
         {!this.state.isDisabled &&
        (<button disabled={this.state.isDisabled} onClick={() => this.handSubmit()}>
          submit
        </button>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Sudharson Basically just CSS code in the format of a dictionary.

Comment: bro iam using this code perfect working but iam using list of user iam clicked approve button let change the status pending to approved . iam click the button hide button but all list of user hiding but i want particular user click then button hide.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code below. You should use conditional rendering, this will hide the elements (remove from DOM)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default class ButtonDemo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isDisabled: false,
    };
  }
  handSubmit() {
    this.setState({
      isDisabled: true,
    });
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <input></input>
        {!this.state.isDisabled &&(
         <button onClick= {()=>this.handSubmit()}>
          submit
        </button>) }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: error accured some error please check iam try this code

Comment: @Sudharson Can you mark it as answered if it solves your question?

Comment: The code will throw an error, because the positions of **}** and **)** after the button element have to be inversed.

Comment: @Bialomazur Haha ,you are right, fixed it.

Comment: list of button id use to hide the button how